# webkit-transform rotate property displays black artifacts after each word

Tags: webkit-transform

I'm trying to use webkits transform rotate property inside a .mobi file for an e-book for Amazon. When I use the property in the css it displays very small but noticeable black artifacts towards the bottom right of each word. It's like a period at the end of a sentence but not as clean. It looks like small dust particles on your camera lens if that's how I have to explain it. This problem is displaying "only" on the 1st generation Kindle Fire, not the Kindle Fire HD 8.9" which looks awesome. None of the browsers are displaying this behavior either. I even tried it with other type faces so I know it's not the font. It goes away when I delete the transform property, that's obvious. Do I need to add anything else?
The main thing is is that it doesn't show on the KF HD. Perhaps it's the result in the HD having double the screen ppi? So maybe it's still there but you just can't see it?
Any pointers and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Html:
div id="fs0-1-txt" class="txt fs0-txt1"
<p>text</p></div>

CSS:
fs0-txt1 
top: 82%;
left: 68%;
width: 40%;
transform: rotate(-3deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);

@font-face 
font-family: "font";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url(../fonts/font.ttf);
```